# Create Polars Dataframe From List of Lists

Tags: dataframe, list, python-polars

I would like to take a list of lists where the first row are column names and load it into a Polars Dataframe in one line so I get maximum performance.

In Pandas, I would do this:

```py
table = [['Heading1', 'Heading2'], [1 , 2], [3, 4]]

df = pd.DataFrame(table[1:], columns=table[0])
```

But in Polars its not clear. I would like to avoid having to serialize the data first (eg to use read_csv).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the same, but `columns=` is replaced with `schema=`

```py
pl.DataFrame(table[1:], schema=table[0])
```

```py
shape: (2, 2)
┌──────────┬──────────┐
│ Heading1 ┆ Heading2 │
│ ---      ┆ ---      │
│ i64      ┆ i64      │
╞══════════╪══════════╡
│ 1        ┆ 3        │
│ 2        ┆ 4        │
└──────────┴──────────┘
```

Polars attempts to infer the orientation from the data, so you may want to explictly set it to `row` in this case.

```py
pl.DataFrame(table[1:], schema=table[0], orient="row")
```

```py
shape: (2, 2)
┌──────────┬──────────┐
│ Heading1 ┆ Heading2 │
│ ---      ┆ ---      │
│ i64      ┆ i64      │
╞══════════╪══════════╡
│ 1        ┆ 2        │
│ 3        ┆ 4        │
└──────────┴──────────┘
```